# Windows Phone 7 Local Database Explicit Transaction

Tags: silverlight, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

Does Windows Phone 7.5 Mango local database support explicit transactions? I could not find any implementation of TransactionScope class which is available to LINQ to SQL in .NET 4. If not, is there any other way to implement an all-or-nothing transactions to the local database?

Answer (score 2):

As I know you cannot specify TransactionScope. But I'n not sure that you really need any explicit transactions, because according to documentation Linq2Sql will maintain two copies of object and determine during SubmitChanges whether to update or not the data so I think you can feel yourself safe during data commit.

Comment: Just found this tool: http://coolstorage.codeplex.com/. Maybe be it will be useful to look at, but I've never tried it and some people have issues with using CoolStorage and SqLite on Windows Phone 7

Comment: I'm not really concerned with LINQ-to-SQL's capability to detect changes or concurrency errors. But rather, I was looking for something similar to TransactionScope where I can update multiple records from multiple tables. Complicating it a bit more, some records may be updated based on the values of other records from different tables. But when any error occurs, all of the changes I made to all the tables must be discarded regardless if some of them succeeded.

Comment: Updating records from multiple tables is fine.  When you call .SubmitChanges() _all_ changes to entities associated with that DataContext are updated in an atomic fashion.